# FirebaseVisionAPIs (MLkit) fails when enableContours and enableLandmarks are true on Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, artificial-intelligence, firebase-mlkit

If I remove the commented line and activate `enableLandmarks: true`, `enableContours: true`, FirebaseVision does not return any face detections or bounding box. If they are disabled I get at least a bounding box.

```
final FaceDetector faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
    FaceDetectorOptions(mode: FaceDetectorMode.fast, enableTracking: true,
     //enableLandmarks: true, enableContours: true
     ));
```

What am I doing wrong? This is a bit of random behavior though.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough resource to maintain the firebase mlkit flutter plugin. Please consider using the [new mlkit native android and iOS SDKs](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) if possible. We are considering to support flutter plugin for the new mlkit. Please let us know any feedbacks you have and we will adjust priority base on that.

Comment: How can I use those native SDKs in flutter? Is there a process?